# Positioning ModalPopupExtender above another ModalPopupExtender

Tags: asp.net, ajax

The first ModalPopupExtender appears in the center of the screen, when i show the second ModalPopupExtender it appears bellow and to  the right of the first one (though above the first one).

I want to place it in the center of the screen.

Update:

I found that the problem with second popup was:

```
PopupDragHandleControlID="pnlDragMe"
```

if i remove this, it's ok.
but i need the drag-control!

This is my drag panel:

```
 <div id="pnlDragMe" class="pnlDragMe">
           Image Uploader
      </div>
```

and it's css:

```
.pnlDragMe
{
    background-color: #4D676A;
    height: 24px;
    cursor: move;
    width: 100%;
    text-indent: 10px;
}
```

Page Layout CSS:

```
/* General styles */
    body {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        border:0;           
        width:100%;
        background:#fff;
        min-width:600px;    

        font-size:90%;
    }
    a {
        color:#369;
    }


    /* column container */
    .colmask {
        position:relative;      
        clear:both;
        float:left;
        width:100%;         
        overflow:hidden;    
    }
    /* 2 column left menu settings */
    .leftmenu {
        background:#FFD8B7;
    }
    .leftmenu .colright {
        float:left;
        width:200%;
        position:relative;
        left:195px;
        background:#fff;
    }
    .leftmenu .col1wrap {
        float:right;
        width:50%;
        position:relative;
        right:200px;
        padding-bottom:1em;
    }
    .leftmenu .col1 {
        margin: 0 5px 0 205px;
        position:relative;
        right:100%;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    .leftmenu .col2 {
        float:left;        
        position:relative;
        /*width:170px;
        right:185px;*/
        width:170px;
        right:190px;
    }
    /* Footer styles */
    #footer {
        clear:both;
        float:left;
        width:100%;
        border-top:1px solid #000;
    }
    #footer p {
        padding:10px;
        margin:0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery center plugin](http://andreaslagerkvist.com/jquery/center/)

This works for me very well